Firebase OnSuccessListener times out when I try to wait for it to finish
I'm trying to load data from my Firebase Firestore database. This code uses an OnSuccessListener which runs async so I'm trying to wait till it loads data to continue. I have done this by creating a while loop that runs until the OnSuccess function sets the variable to true.
Here is the code:
public FragmentData getFragData(String fragType)
    {
        cont = false;
        Log.d("useremail", currentUser.getEmail());
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(currentUser.getEmail()).collection("FragmentData").document(fragType);
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                returnData = documentSnapshot.toObject(FragmentData.class);
                cont = true;
                Log.d("testhi", "" + returnData.getId().get(0));
            }
        });
        while(!cont);
        //find a way to fix the fact that onSuccess doesn't process in time so return data is always null
        Log.d("testhi", "" + returnData.getId().get(0));
        return returnData;
    }

When I do this, the while loop stops the OnSuccess Function from happening but I am wondering why since the OnSuccess function should be working async from the normal function. If there's no way to salvage this I am wondering how I should go about this since if I don't do this, returnData is null since it doesn't load in time.

This is not the right way to do asynchronous programming.  Your loop is "spamming" the main thread so that the result can't come back from the listener, and is effectively locking up the entire app.  You should continue processing the result of the call inside the onSuccess listener, or arrange for some other thread to handle the result without blocking the main thread.

@DougStevenson I did that for a similar example to this, the only problem is that when I try to return the data inside the success listener it doesn't let me since the onSuccessListener is a void function and doesn’t process it as me returning a value for the “getFragData” function

There is no way you can return the returnData object as a result of a method. Please remember that Firebase API is asynchronous. This means that the solution is always the same. Any code that needs data from a Cloud Firestore database, needs to be inside the onSuccess method or be called from there. So in your case, the value of the returnData object should be used only inside the onSuccess method.
Or, if you need to wait for the data, then you can use a callback as explained in my answer in the following post:

How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?

Or you can use a LiveData object as explained in the following answer:

How to properly get the results from firestore database fetches embracing ascynchronous functionality? - Android - Kotlin - MVVM

Or if you understand Kotlin, you can also use Kotlin Coroutines as explained below:

How to return a list from Firestore database as a result of a function in Kotlin?


Hey there. Have you tried one of the solutions above, does it work for you?
